# Field update on Product2

Tags: apex

The last part of my code which should update the Opportunity_Owner_notification checkbox, does not seem to be working as I have no checkbox as True. Any idea as to what's going wrong?

```
global class OpOwnerOldService_Scheduled Implements Schedulable
{
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
    {
        sendEmailtoOppOwner();
    }

    public void sendEmailtoOppOwner()
    {
        List<Opportunity> listOpportunity = new List<Opportunity>();
        listOpportunity = [SELECT Id, OwnerId, Name, Owner.FirstName, (SELECT Id, Product2.Name FROM OpportunityLineItems LIMIT 1) FROM Opportunity WHERE Id In (SELECT OpportunityId FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Product2.Opportunity_Owner_Notification__c = FALSE)];

        for(Opportunity opp : listOpportunity)
        {
           Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

mail.setTargetObjectId(opp.OwnerId);
mail.setReplyTo('glenn.daly@live.com');
mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Support');
for(opportunitylineitem oppLineItem :opp.opportunitylineitems)                
mail.setSubject('Historic Service attached to current opportunity : ' + oppLineItem.Product2.Name);

String body = 'Hi '+ opp.Owner.FirstName + ', ';     
       body += '<br><br>Salesforce recognises you as the owner of the following opportunity:'+ opp.Name;
            for(opportunitylineitem oppLineItem :opp.opportunitylineitems)
       body += '<br><br>Attached to this opportunity is a former R&D service or project that is no longer available:' + oppLineItem.Product2.Name;
       body += '<br><br> Please use the link below to view the opportunity record:';
       body += '<br><br>test.salesforce.com/'+ opp.id;     
mail.setHtmlBody(body);
mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);

Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });

for(opportunitylineitem oppLineItem :opp.opportunitylineitems)
oppLineItem.product2.Opportunity_Owner_Notification__c = TRUE;
        update listOpportunity;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code formatting is difficult to read (there appear to be some extra for loops, and the indentation is inconsistent). Would you please take a few moments to edit your post? Even just getting opening/closing braces around each of your for loops would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not updating the product, or even the opportunity line items; you're updating the opportunities themselves. Instead, you need to construct a list of products and update them. Something like this:

```
Map<Id, Product2> products = new Map<Id, Product2>();
for(Opportunity opp: listOpportunity) {
  for(OpportunityLineItem oppLineItem: opp.opportunitylineitems) {
    products.put(oppLineItem.Product2Id, new Product2(Id=oppLineItem.Product2Id, Opportunity_Owner_Notification__c=true));
  }
}
update products.values();
```

Make sure you're not updating the products *per opportunity*, but instead all once at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this, the only problem is that I don't know where to put the code you mention. Should it come after the updatelistopportunity?

Comment: @GlennDaly You're not modifying the opportunity records, so there's no need to have that entire chunk of code in your class. This code should replace the last three or so lines of code in the sendEmailToOppOwner method.

Comment: this is what I've tried, but by doing that I get the error "Variable does not exist: record.Product2Id"

Comment: @GlennDaly Sorry, it's habit. I fixed the answer.

Comment: I have included the code after the first closed bracket after update listopportunity; and it's showing the following error "Variable does not exist: listProducts"

Comment: @GlennDaly Just another typo. I've updated the code again.